# XSL wrapping method for URLs

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Sorry I dont have a better title for this, if I could think of a better way to word it, i could probably find an answer :-/

I have some XML data that looks like

```
<maml:navigationLink>
    <maml:linkText>some text</maml:linkText>
    <maml:uri />
</maml:navigationLink>
```

Now in some cases the URI is empty, and in others its not. I'd like to make it a link if there is a URI otherwise just text.

I know i could use a Choose like so

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="maml:uri !=''">
    <a href="{maml:uri}"><xsl:value-of select="maml:linkText"/></a>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="maml:linkText"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

but I have another, more complex situation, that requires the same sort of yes/no wrapping, only it goes a few levels deep, which would make it a tad more complex.

The more complex example would be something like

```
<parameter required='true'  position='true'>
  <maml:name>Name</maml:name>
  <maml:type>String</maml:type>
</parameter>
```

And I need the result to look something like

```
[[-Name] <String>]
```

the outer most [] is the "required" flag, the inner [] is if the 'position' is true.

this is even a simplification of the full extent of it, but thats enough to show the nested aspect of it.

Is there some sort of shortcut to doing something similar to this?

Comment: Can you give vivid examples in XML and your desired output? That would give us less time to imagine things and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method i came up with, using variables, and more detailed XML to work with.

Here is the XML

```
<command:parameter required="false" variableLength="true" globbing="true" pipelineInput="True (ByPropertyName)" position="1" aliases="ProcessName">
      <maml:name>Name</maml:name>
      <maml:description>
        <maml:para>Specifies one or more processes by process name. You can type multiple process names (separated by commas) and use wildcard characters. The parameter name ("Name") is optional.</maml:para>
      </maml:description>
      <command:parameterValue required="true" variableLength="true">String[]      </command:parameterValue>
    </command:parameter>
```

This is the solution i came up with.

```
  <xsl:template match="command:parameter" mode="syntax">
    <xsl:variable name="pName">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@position !='named'">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('[-',maml:name,']')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('-',maml:name)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="pType">
        <xsl:if test="command:parameterValue !=''">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(' &lt;', command:parameterValue,'>')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@required ='true'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',$pName,$pType)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' [',$pName,$pType,'] ')"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
```

The output looks like this

```
Get-Process [[-Name] <String[]>]  [-ComputerName <String[]>]  [-FileVersionInfo]  [-Module]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

For this more nested situation, the variable makes sense, but for the URL if i use a variable it's about as much code, if not more.